# Having trouble iterating through a list of Song tuples

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples

The tuples being used are as followed:

```
Album = namedtuple('Album', 'id artist title year songs')

# id is a unique ID number; artist and title are strings; year is a number,
#   the year the song was released; songs is a list of Songs

Song = namedtuple('Song', 'track title length play_count')

# track is the track number; title is a string; length is the number of
#   seconds long the song is; play_count is the number of times the user
#   has listened to the song

def Song_str(S: Song)->str:
    '''Takes a song and returns a string containing that songs
    information in an easily readible format'''

    return '{:12}{}\n{:12}{}\n{:12}{}\n{:12}{}'.format('Track:', S.track,
                                                       'Title:', S.title,
                                                       'Length:', S.length,
                                                       'Play Count:', S.play_count)

def Album_str(a: Album)->str:
    '''Takes an album and returns a string containing that songs
    information in an easily readible format'''

    Album_Songs = a.songs
    for i in range(0, len(Album_Songs)):
            String = Song_str(Album_Songs[i])+ '\n'

    return '{:10}{}\n{:10}{}\n{:10}{}\n{:10}{}\n\n{}\n{}'.format('ID:', a.id,
                                                                'Artist:', a.artist,
                                                                'Title:', a.title,
                                                                'Year:', a.year,
                                                                'List of Songs:', String)

print(Album_str(AN ALBUM))
```

The album info is printing fine but when it gets to printing songs of the albums which is a list of the tuple song it will either print the first or last songs info on that list

Comment: This is no-where near correct **Python** syntax.

Comment: @HennyH: Nothing looks obviously wrong to me. Maybe you don't know about [function annotations](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/)? I haven't used Python 3, so I'm not quite sure how to use them, but these look like function annotations to me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, ignoring the fact that your method definitions aren't correct python, your exact error is on here:

```
String = Song_str(Album_Songs[i])+ '\n'
```

Each iteration of an album, you're re-establishing the variable named `String`. Here's what you actually wanted:

```
def Album_str(a):
    '''Takes an album and returns a string containing that songs
    information in an easily readible format'''

    Album_Songs = a.songs
    list_of_songs = []
    for album_song in Album_Songs:  # Don't use list indexing, just iterate over it.
        list_of_songs.append(Song_str(album_song))

    return '{:10}{}\n{:10}{}\n{:10}{}\n{:10}{}\n\n{}\n{}'.format('ID:', a.id,
                                                                'Artist:', a.artist,
                                                                'Title:', a.title,
                                                                'Year:', a.year,
                                                                'List of Songs:', '\n'.join(list_of_songs))
```

Also, don't use the variable name `String`.

Comment: How are the definitions not correct Python? http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/